# Should the size of entities be as small as possible when I count them by "count()" method?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm wondering if I should have a kind only for counting entities.

For example
There is a model like the following.

```
class Message(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    message = db.StringProperty()
    created_on = db.DateTimeProperty()
    created_by = db.ReferenceProperty(User)
    category = db.StringProperty()
```

And there are 100000000 entities made of this model.
I want to count entities which category equals 'book'.
In this case, should I create the following mode for counting them?

```
class Category(db.Model):
    category = db.StringProperty()
    look_message = db.ReferenceProperty(Message)
```

Does this small model make it faster to count?
And does it erase smaller memory?

I'm thinking to count them like the following by the way

```
q = db.Query(Message).filter('category =', 'book')
count = q.count(10000)
```

Comment: i think you should reformulate your question and add some code. what are your expectations what are your expected results.

Comment: I don't think that model size effects count()

Comment: I've never seen it (size) referenced in the count() docs.

Comment: so, it's really just counting them, not reading properties?

Comment: I think count() just walks through the indexes and counts, it doesn't actually fetch the entity.  This is reflected in the cost, since count() costs a small op instead of a full read op.

Comment: Thank you dragonx. Your answer perfectly made me clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have to create another entity like this.
This entity will just count the number of messages by category.
Just change your category to this:

```
class Category(db.model):
   category = db.StringProperty()
   totalOfMessages = db.IntegerProperty(default=0)
```

In the message class you change to reference the category class, just change the category property to:

```
category = db.ReferenceProperty(Category)
```

When you create a new Message object, you have to update the counter, increment when you create a new message or decrement if you delete.

The best way to work with counters on GAE is using [Sharding Counters](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters)

Answer (score 2):

Counting 100000000 entities is a very expensive operation on a NoSQL database as the App Engine datastore. You'll probably want to count as you update, or run a map-reduce operation to count after the fact.

App Engine also offers a simple way to query how many entities of each type you have:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/stats

For example, to count all Messages:

```
from google.appengine.ext.db import stats

kind_stats = stats.KindStat().all().filter("kind_name =", "Message").get()
count = kind_stats.count
```

Note that stats are updated asynchronously, so they'll lag the actual count.

Comment: Thank you for the beneficial information. I didn't know the kind 'stats'. Now I know that I don't have to execute the counting loop to count all entities of a kind.

Answer (score 1):

Count is implemented as an index scan that discards all data except the number of records seen . It never looks up the entity, so the size of the entity does not matter.

That being said, counting like this does not scale and is quite costly in a system without a fixed schema. It would likely be better to use another method like a Sharded Counter, MapReduce or Materialized View/Fork Join. If you really want it to scale, this talk is pretty informative: http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/high-throughput-data-pipelines-appengine.html